# What film/TV program was set on a spaceship and...? (I can only remember the ending so have kept the title uninformative!)

Tags: story-identification, spaceship, apocalypse

Like the title says, I only remember the end of this. I think it was a film, but may have been an episode of something like The Outer Limits. I saw it on TV around 1999 (ish), and I think it was quite new then.

I've looked through all the episodes of the Outer Limits and haven't been able to find it, but maybe I missed it.

I remember that there was a spaceship with a number of crew aboard, and I think a robot. One of the crew was a drug addict. Something went wrong and the ship was going to explode, but there was only room for 2 (one woman, one man went) in the single escape pod. The other 2 (also one woman, one man) people on board (there may have been more earlier in the program) decided to overdose on the addict's drugs rather than just be blown up. You see the escape pod reaching some distance and see the main ship explode.

Then suddenly they 'wake up' in a room. The two people who overdosed are dead in that room, as are other people that had been on the ship who have been dead for a while. The 2 people left leave the room and find a long dead man guarding another door. They open the door and find what looked like a nuclear winter. ..And that's the end.

Any ideas on what this is?

Comment: This has some similarity to the Red Dwarf episode "Back to Reality" which aired in 1992, although it's obviously a different story.

Comment: Definitely not Red Dwarf :o), but your comment did make me remember that the people had US accents.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This literally drove me nuts for the better part of the last 24 hours.  I knew I had seen that somewhere before...

It's the ending of [Terminal Voyage](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114533/) from 1994.  [Wiki link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_Voyage)