# Oldish Sci-Fi film where a crew is stuck on a ship and slowly die off only to find out it was a trick at the end

Tags: story-identification

Trying to identify this movie I saw a long time ago.  I watched it in the 90s but it was probably from the 80s and not terribly well done either.  Probably B-Movie levels.

I can only remember a few points:
There's a ship in deep space and there's a crew of a maybe ~6-8 characters.
Stuff happens where characters are slowly killed off.  The only one I remember was a VR machine they use for relaxation.  One guy uses it for VR sex but gets killed during the session.
Everyone is tense about the mysterious deaths.
Something happens (I think the life support breaks?) and this causes a lot of strife among the crew members who slowly kill each other off.
Finally there's like 2 people left after everyone else is dead and they are close to death and they just decide to space themselves so they open the hatch and find out they were on earth (or some planet anyway) all along.  Iirc, the planet looked like a post-apocalyptic one with ruined cities.  It was a simulation to test them or something like that.

Any ideas?

NB: It's not 'Alien Intruder' from '93, that one has the VR aspect, but the film I'm thinking about had the VR as only a minor thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could you be thinking of *[Terminal Voyage](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/154297/movie-identification-spaceship-earth-destroyed-but-not-really/154302#154302)* from 1994?

To quote my prior answer:

> In 2035, global warming rendered the Earth barely inhabitable and its human population is on the verge of extinction. The Earth Federation sends a space ship on a century-long trip to a distant planet Trion which could be suitable for colonization. The eight crew-members come from Russia, United States, China, United Kingdom, France, and Saudi Arabia.
>
> As the ship approaches Trion, the crew wakes from hibernation. They immediately find a decomposed corpse of the Captain in his capsule. The ship's XO, Commander Hollis, assumes command. When he reads a secure transmission from Earth received while they were sleeping, he commits suicide, leaving a note that he "joins his loved ones". The new CO, Lieutenant Jammad, reveals the content of the message: the Earth has been devastated in a nuclear holocaust.

....

> When questioned, Becker denies any guilt then sets off the self-destruction sequence. Granier and Han are too devastated to continue and commit suicide with a morphine overdose, and Reese and Zinovitz make it to the escape capsule. As the countdown reaches zero, they find themselves in an underground simulation facility stationed on Earth. There was no space flight - it is their final test, an "extreme stress simulation" scenario which involved the death of the commanding officer and multiple system failures. The crew have only been in hibernation for 6 months, and Hollis, Jammad and Becker apparently knew about the test.

The kicker is:

> However the nuclear war on Earth was indeed real, and the facility is empty and abandoned. The film ends with a view of a destroyed city, as Reese and Zinovitz look on to uncertain future.

Comment: Thanks, I think I was confusing another film with this one regarding the crew fighting each other.  I also didn't remember the android at all!